# How do I change font size in a rendered PDF doc in iText?

Tags: pdf, itext, font-size

I’m using iText 2.1.7, included through the following dependency …

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

How do I change the text size of a PDF field in a PDF I’m trying to export?  I created a PDF template using OpenOffice 4.1.0 and then have tried this code to set the text size:

```
            final PdfReader pdfTemplate = new PdfReader(pdfTemplateFile.toString());
            // Prepare to generate a byte output stream
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfTemplate, out);
            stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
    …
            stamper.getAcroFields().setField(PARTICIPANT_FIELD_NAME, user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName());
            stamper.getAcroFields().setFieldProperty(PARTICIPANT_FIELD_NAME, "textsize", new Float(36), null);
            final BaseFont font = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            stamper.getAcroFields().setFieldProperty(PARTICIPANT_FIELD_NAME, "textfont", font, null);
```

No matter what value I put in between “new Float(xxx)”, the font size is always rendered the same.  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The appearance of the field is generated at the moment you set the field with the `setField()` method. This means that you're doing things in the wrong order. Change your code like this:

```
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
form.setFieldProperty(PARTICIPANT_FIELD_NAME, "textsize", new Float(36), null);
final BaseFont font = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
form.setFieldProperty(PARTICIPANT_FIELD_NAME, "textfont", font, null);
form.setField(PARTICIPANT_FIELD_NAME, user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName());
```

As for your use of iText 2.1.7, obviously that's [not a good idea](http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq), but we'd like to know why you prefer using obsolete software, so we've hired Black Duck Software to help us with [this survey](https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/iText-community).

Comment: I thought I read somewhere that higher versions of 2.1.7 have some kind of restrictive license agreement but I haven't had time to read through the license details.